# Detect if a key is bound to something in vim

Tags: vim, key-bindings

I'd like to know if there is a way to figure out if a key does something in vim. I know that I can use `:map` to see user-defined mappings, but is there something for the built-in stuff?

For example, I always had <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd> bound to close tab, because I thought that it was unused. After half a year, I found out that there are some sequences that use it, like <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd> to split the window, and it was a nightmare to retrain myself.

Comment: Speaking of accidental collisions of user-defined mappings, it's really a good practice to use [_mapleader_](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#mapleader)

Answer (score 98, accepted):

If you check out the suggested answer by Randy Morris you will find that

```
:help index
```

will give you the list you want.

Comment: very useful! good to know there's a place you can go look if you just want to poke around to learn something new

Answer (score 56):

To check the default mapping:

```
:help index
```

For other mapping that is done by either users or plugin:

```
:map
:map!
```

From [http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-*Tutorial*(Part_1)](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-_Tutorial_%28Part_1%29):

> The first command displays the maps that work in normal, visual and
>   select and operator pending mode. The second command displays the maps
>   that work in insert and command-line mode.
>
> Typically the output of the above commands will span several pages.
>   You can use the following set of commands to redirect the output to
>   the vim_maps.txt file:
>
> ```
> :redir! > vim_maps.txt
> :map
> :map!
> :redir END
> ```

Comment: Unless newer versions of Vim suddenly offers a better alternative, this seems to be the only way to search both included and custom keymaps. `mapcheck` (as mentioned in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19726877/6296561)) also only covers custom keybinds. The main difference between outputting to a text file and mapcheck is that outputting to a text file and/or using `:help index` lets you `/C-w` in Vim to find anything using `C-w`

Answer (score 39):

Not a complete answer, but you may want to check out `:help map-which-keys` for a list of keys that vim recommends you to use in your custom maps.

That help section has a recommendation of how to tell if a specific key is mapped to an action.

Answer (score 23):

I skimmed through `:help index` and made a list of some of the unused `nmap` keys:

- Q (switch to "Ex" mode)
- Z except ZZ, ZQ
- \
- `<Space>` (same as `l` in the normal mode; the largest and the most underutilized key in the normal mode)
- gb, gc, gl, gx, gy, gz
- gs (sleep)
- zp, zq, zu, zy
- cd, cm, co, cp, cq, cr, cs, cu, cx, cy
- dc, dm, do, dp, dq, dr, ds, du, dx, dy
- gA, gB, gC, gG, gK, gL, gM, gO, gS, gX, gY, gZ
- zB, zI, zJ, zK, zP, zQ, zP, zS, zT, zU, zV, zY, zZ
- ]a, ]b, ]e, ]g, ]h, ]j, ]k, ]l, ]n, ]o, ]q, ]r, ]t, ]u, ]v, ]w, ]x, ]y
- [a, [b, [e, [g, [h, [j, [k, [l, [n, [o, [q, [r, [t, [u, [v, [w, [x, [y
- CTRL-G, CTRL-K
- CTRL-\ a - z (reserved for extensions)
- CTRL-\ A - Z (not used)

Please update/comment.

Comment: Ctrl-w is used by default for window operations

Answer (score 19):

Use `:map!` and `:map` for manually set keys and `:help 'char(-combination)'` to find out which keys are already mapped in vim out-of-the-box(/out of your specific compiling options).
(Slightly off-topic but still regardable (I think): Use `:scriptnames` to see which files have been sourced in which order.)

Comment: If you want to search for what keys trigger a certain command, you can do this:
  :redir keys.txt 
  :map 
  :redir end

Then open keys.txt and search for what commands are bound.

Answer (score 15):

You can use `mapcheck`.:-

For example, I wanted to map `<CR> ,i` to `gg=G` to indented a file.
To check if there is a mapping already for `<CR> , i`

```
if mapcheck("\<CR>", "I") == "" |echo "no mapping"
```

...but this won't detect if the mapping is part of a sequence.

Comment: I tried to check if "o" is bound to something in normal mode, with the following: if mapcheck("o", "N") == "" | echo "no mapping" but it reports "no mapping", when o is definitely bound to "open new line". Am I using it wrong?

Comment: @K.Norbert: I believe this for user defined mappings

Answer (score 2):

Only to complete this very old post, the following will print if and by what source a specific keybinding was set.  In the event the mappings collided/overlapped, the `verbose` keyword will provide you the list of which sources set the binding. e.g., for `<C-n>`... in normal mode:

```
:verbose nmap <C-n>
```