# Vim: list free keybindings

Tags: vim, key-bindings

Is there some way to list unused keybinds?
I guess if the answer is no, it would be a good feature-request (especially for these undecided types like myself).

Edit:
To make it more precise, I know you can list bindings with:

```
:map
:nmap
:imap
```

FFI see:

```
:help map-modes
```

and manually check whether given binding is used by typing e.g.:

```
:help Ctrl-w
:help ^w
```

FFI see:

```
:help map
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483849/detect-if-a-key-is-bound-to-something-in-vim

Comment: This doesn't answer your question but is related (for future searches).  You may be interested in `:help map-which-keys`.

Comment: @RandyMorris - great help topic suggestion! I was actually missing something like this: http://hea-www.harvard.edu/~fine/Tech/vi.html - but for Vim. Then I found out about `:help index` - which is also great. I need some mappings for missing functionality (e.g. in Cmder `^W` will kill your console, and `^V` pastes clipboard (and Alt-^-V does nothing).

Comment: What does "FFI" mean? "For further information"?

Answer (score 11):

To my knowledge there is no way to list the unused key-bindings (this would
be impossible because there is an infinite number of them).

But if you want to go the other way around you can type:

```
:map

:imap
```

to list the user defined key-bindings.

Also  if you type

```
:help index
```

you can check if some key-binding is already assigned to a function in vim.

Comment: It's infinite but you can definitely introduce some order into that set or add maximal length parameter.