# Keys and key combinations in Vim with no function

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts

In Vim I (of course) use keymappings to make my life easier, but when making a key mapping of my own I would really know if that key (or key combination) had some purpose before I potentially remap it.

So my question is: which keys/key combinations in Vim does not have a function? and is there by any chance a way to get Vim to list which?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect if a key is bound to something in vim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483849/detect-if-a-key-is-bound-to-something-in-vim)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generally use `:help <key>` to see if it's taken in normal mode and `:help i_<key>` to see if it's used in insert mode. Furthermore, you can use `:map <key>` to check if anything is mapped by your vimrc or plugins. This also works for `imap`, `nmap`, etc.

For example:

```
:help j
:help i_CTRL-N
:imap <Tab>
```

As far as a list goes, all of the capital and lowercase letters from A-Z have some meaning assigned to them. Most `CTRL+<key>` keys have meaning in all modes but some don't. The default `<leader>` key is `\`, but many people set that to `,`; however, `,` has a special meaning in normal mode (opposite of `;`). I suspect that most people map custom keys to `<leader><key>` or an `<F#>`. Often times keys that do have a default meaning aren't ones you actually desire, so looking up `:help` is a good practice since it not only increases your understanding of vim but also lets you make a judgment call on whether you need that functionality or not.